# Invalid syntax error while using pandas with query function

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a dataset to query, and while using multiple queries I'm getting a syntax error. I'd appreciate if anyone here can point out where I'm going wrong.

The line where I get the error is:

```
subscribers = bike_trips_df.query("usertype == 'Subscriber' & birth year >= 1999")
```

The error is:

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    usertype =='Subscriber'and birth year >=__pd_eval_local_birthyear
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You should be able to wrap the odd column name in back ticks:  `'Subscriber' and \`birth year\` >= __pd_eval_local_birthyear`, but you might consider renaming the column.

Comment: `Dataframe.query()`  method only works if the column name doesn’t have any empty spaces. So before applying the method, replace spaces in column names with ‘_’. Found this here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filtering-data-with-pandas-query-method/

Answer (score 1):

Pandas don't like spaces in the column names. Just remove and see, it should work.